# fsckopen() timeout when connecting to SMTP

Tags: php, firewall

We use a PHP library that opens a connection to SMTP server to validate certain emails when registering new clients.
After a server change the script has started reporting constant connection timeouts:

> fsockopen(): unable to connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25
>   (Connection timed out) in /home/xxxxxx.php on line 195, referer: xxxxx

We can telnet the server via console as root, but not as apache user so we discarded it to be an iptables firewall issue (we use CSF).

Strange enough, it seems we can fsckopen other pòrts.

We are digging other issues of CSF configuration but so far we are completely lost as no other logs (lfd, iptables, syslog) reports anything.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

If CSF option SMTP_BLOCK is activated (=1) apache user ("www-data" in our case), needs to be added to the SMTP_ALLOWUSER directive for PHP (through Apache) to work with SMTP as a destination.

CSF firewall will block any outgoing connections to SMTP for users not allowed but without any logging to lfd.log